# ElasticSearch: why it is not possible to get suggest by criteria?

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, elasticsearch-query

I want to get suggestions from some text for concrete user. 
As I understand Elasticsearch provides suggestions based on the whole dictionary(inverted index) that contains all the terms in the index.

So if `user1` posts some text then this text can be suggested to user2. Am I right?

Is it possible to add filter by criteria (by user for example) to reduce the set of terms to be suggested?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's very much possible, let me show you by an example, which uses the [query with filter context](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html):

### Index def

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "title": {
                "type": "text" --> inverted index for storing suggestions on title field
            },
            "userId" : {
                "type" : "keyword" --> like in you example
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Index sample doc

```
{
    "title" : "foo baz",
    "userId" : "katrin"
}

{
    "title" : "foo bar",
    "userId" : "opster"
}
```

### Search query without userId filter

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "match": {
                    "title": "foo"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Search results(bring both results)

```
 "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "so_suggest",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.18232156,
                "_source": {
                    "title": "foo bar",
                    "userId": "posted" --> note another user
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "so_suggest",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 0.18232156,
                "_source": {
                    "title": "foo baz",
                    "userId": "katrin" -> note user
                }
            }
        ]
```

### Now lets reduce the suggestion by filtering the docs created by user `katrin`

### Search query

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "match": {
                    "title": "foo"
                }
            },
            "filter": {. --> note filter on userId field
                "term": {
                    "userId": "katrin"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Search result

```
 "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "so_suggest",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 0.18232156,
                "_source": {
                    "title": "foo baz",
                    "userId": "katrin"
                }
            }
        ]
```

Comment: It looks like ordinary search isn't it? I want to get suggests by term with fuzziness such the following: 

{
 
  "suggest" : {
    "my-suggestion" : {
      "text" : "tst",
      "term" : {
        "field" : "text",
        "suggest_mode": "always",
       
        "min_word_length" : 1
      }
    }
  }
}

And I want to add filter so the result only contains the terms matched criteria. Other words I want to get a list of fuzziness terms by my origin term. But suggested terms should be filtered by criteria.

Comment: @katrin, yes what i provided is for ordinary search, looks like I missed that you are looking for suggestions, not the search results, are you looking something like this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/search-suggesters.html#search-suggesters

Comment: Yes, I need something like this but.. with the filter by criteria)

Comment: @katrin, hv not used this in details and quick lookup shows it not possible, btw what is your actual use case? and sorry for jumping the gun quickly would remove my answer

Comment: let's back to chat) https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210597/discussion-between-opster-elasticsearch-ninja-and-katrin